# how to join strings in python in order to get a multiline text so \n represents a new line and not a character?

Tags: python, regex, string, newline

Given a list of strings: `['string_a', 'string_b', 'string_c']`

If I join those strings with a `\n`:

`'\n'.join(['string_a', 'string_b', 'string_c'])`

The result is (case 0): `'string_a\nstring_b\nstring_c'`

And if I print the result (case 1):

```
string_a
string_b
string_c
```

Given that I want to find the line containing string_b and everything below it using regex, but this is what I find: https://regex101.com/r/yF4u2I/1

The regex `r'string_b\n.+'` can find the text in the case 1 but cannot find it in the case 0.

But if I change the regex to `r'string_b\\n.+'` it finds the text only in the case 0. This happens because the `\n` is being considered a character and not a newline.

How can I join a list of strings in order to have a multiline string? Or what could be another way of using regex to find that?

Comment: did you try printing it? `print('\n'.join(['string_a', 'string_b', 'string_c']))`

Comment: *"This happens because the \n is being considered a character and not a newline."*... `\n` **is** a character, commonly rendered as a newline. Check, instead, markers for begin-of-line and end-of-line in regexps, those may help

Comment: Your string cannot really be rendered as `string_a\nstring_b\nstring_c` unless the ` \ ` has been escaped, that's why `r'string_b\\n.+'` will find it there.

Comment: @GPhilo it doesn't work. I tried to use ^ (for start) and $ (for end) and it doesn't match any.

Comment: @mad_ But how could I print it to a variable instead of printing it to stdout?

Comment: @GustavoMaia `^string_b\n.+$`? Or do you want all lines below `string_b`?

Comment: You can use an alternative here: `string_b(?:\n|\\n).+` [see forked regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5PUxbT/1)

Comment: Your `'\n'.join(['string_a', 'string_b', 'string_c'])` is doing what you ask in the title as `'\n'` is a **newline, LF, character**.

Comment: @Kaddath it works fine, but I get to another problem: the actual text I want to find is not all the lines after `string_b`, I nee lines that follow a pattern and this doesn't work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but regex doesn't see it as a newline but as a string character

Comment: Newline is a string. Regex never "sees" anything, it matches a text with a pattern or not, that is all. If you want to match a newline, use a newline, `\n`, in the regex. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Beware that the `.` in your last `.+` means `any character except for line terminators`, as regex101 itself states, that's why you don't get them, try with `[\s\S]+` instead

Comment: @Kaddath this is actually what I am doing https://regex101.com/r/E1Rnc6/2

Comment: And then why don't you 1) set the Python option and 2) use the [automatically generated code](https://regex101.com/r/RjjOXG/1/codegen?language=python)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because it is not working the way I want it to work. The second block of text in the link is the text with the `\n` and the result of it is different from the result of the first block of text. What I need is the second block to have a result identical to the first block.

Comment: And which is the way you want? Your question and comments are not clear. Provide 1) real literal string or - better - string literal you want to work with, 2) explain what you need to match in that string

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunatelly I can't provide the real string. Sorry for the confusion in the first link. What I need is these two (https://regex101.com/r/fO2ad9/1 , https://regex101.com/r/GCAVUc/1) to have the same result

Comment: Which is the result? Which result is correct? Here - https://regex101.com/r/fO2ad9/1 or - https://regex101.com/r/GCAVUc/1 here? We can't read your thoughts.

Comment: This is the correct https://regex101.com/r/fO2ad9/1

Comment: Great, it is clear now. Use `r'STRING:((?:(?:\n|\\n)+\d+[-.](?:(?!\\n).)*)+)'` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/RRFn5q/1) and [demo](https://regex101.com/r/i9QOfL/1))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a '|' for OR so:

```
r'string_b\n.+|string_b.+'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would rather find a method to have both situations working with one regex only. I simplified the regex a lot to create the question, to have a pattern for each would make it a lot more complicated I think.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use *r* prefix for regex string. r tells regex to treat pattern as raw string.

Use *'string_b\n.+'*

> Unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in strings
>   are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard
>   C. The recognized escape sequences are:
>
> Escape Sequence   Meaning Notes \newline  Ignored   \    Backslash
>   ()     \'    Single quote (')      \"    Double quote (")      \a
>   ASCII Bell (BEL)      \b    ASCII Backspace (BS)      \f    ASCII
>   Formfeed (FF)   \n    ASCII Linefeed (LF)   \N{name}  Character named
>   name in the Unicode database (Unicode only)   \r    ASCII Carriage
>   Return (CR)    \t    ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)    \uxxxx    Character
>   with 16-bit hex value xxxx (Unicode only)  \Uxxxxxxxx    Character
>   with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx (Unicode only)  \v    ASCII Vertical
>   Tab (VT)   \ooo  Character with octal value ooo \xhh  Character with
>   hex value hh

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think the problem is in the target string not in the regex.

Answer (score -2):

```
l=['a','s','c']

''.join(list(i+'\n' for i in l )))
```

this is working well